# Linux Posix Queues Too many files open

Tags: c++, linux, posix

In my application I have different modules which communicate through posix queues, the problem is Im getting the above mentioned error when limit meets, I have set the limit in both

```
sysctl fs.file-max = new_value
```

and

```
ulimit -n
```

but this is some hardcoded value, is there any best practice to overcome this? I tried closing the descriptors by `mq_close` but then again all the modules in application can use any message at any time. So I cannot close all the descriptors.

Comment: You probably aren't hitting the total file descriptor limit but the limits on the number of message queues, a condition which will return ENFILE as well.  You asked a question about this the other day.  Did you increase the number of MQs allowed?

Comment: yup I did as it was suggested, but still getting the error, I am looking for a workaround for it.

Comment: Currently I am making and handler which will keep all the queues descriptors and will only open when needed. But this is not a good approach right?

Comment: (1) What steps did you take? (2) What are the current limits? (3) How many queues is your app/system using?  Will try to pick up tomorrow if no one helps in the meantime.

Comment: Do you open or open lots of files?  There is a limit on open, something like 254, but the limit for open is a lot higher.  If the queues implementation uses open, it will probably hit this.

Comment: I have done it by a new technique will be posting it on codeproject, I made a new shared object and I am storing the names of descriptors in it, only those who will read from the queue will have the descriptors names. By doing this I wont have to worry about any limits anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of resource limits in linux/UNIX Soft limit & Hard limit. The maximum descriptors you can set is up to the hard limit. There are methods to increase hard limit but frankly speaking I have never tried so & neither I would recommend this due to two reasons:

1. Opening too many descriptors concurrently will slow down the performance of your program.
2. It is not even required to increase hard limit since if you close the unused descriptors properly in your program you will see yourself that it is not even required. Imagine a web server that opens a new descriptor for every new request also does not require to increase the hard limit.

Finally I would recommend you even to increase the soft limit please use setrlimit function from your program since increasing the limit on the shell is temporary & if you set it in profile it will increase the limit for all the programs.